# Advanced string edit in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a dataset where the names of companies don't quite match the dataset I'd like to merge with.

As part of the solution, I'd like to edit company names down a column in my data frame. Assuming I a list of company names, what I'd like to do is this:

```
diff = ['some list of tickers']
for security in df.query("tic in @diff").security.unique():
    result = re.search(expression, security)[0].upper()
    result = result.replace('CORPORATION', 'CORP')
    result = result.replace('COMPANY', 'CO')
    result = result.replace('OF','')
    result = result.replace('F', '')
    result = result.strip()
```

I think there might even an elegant solution where I can run a custom function for modifying the value of a cell, but I'm not familiar enough with pandas to know how to do that yet.

The dataframe I'm editing on loks like this.

```
          caldt      tic              security             curshrt
2672    1988-06-01  ITSCW   Industrial Training Systems,    0
8007    1988-07-01  ITSCW   Industrial Training Systems,    0
44772   1989-03-01  MMNT    Momentum, Inc.  0
49865   1989-04-01  MMNT    Momentum, Inc.  372
54925   1989-05-01  MMNT    Momentum, Inc.  78
... ... ... ... ...
1077214 2007-06-01  ABBI    Abraxis BioScience, Inc. - Common stock 4486255
1080530 2007-07-01  ABBI    Abraxis BioScience, Inc. - Common stock 4659919
1083835 2007-08-01  ABBI    Abraxis BioScience, Inc. - Common stock 4265095
1087148 2007-09-01  ABBI    Abraxis BioScience, Inc. - Common stock 4018741
1090424 2007-10-01  ABBI    Abraxis BioScience, Inc. - Common stock 4064510
```

I'm getting rid of punctuation and changing some of the abbreviations and words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your codes may be modified as follows:

```
import re

diff = ['some list of tickers']
d = dict([('CORPORATION', 'CORP'), ('COMPANY', 'CO'), ('OF',''), ('F', '')])
s = df.loc[df.tic.isin(diff), 'security']
df.loc[df.tic.isin(diff), 'security'] = (s.str.findall(expression, flags=re.I).str[0].
                                           str.upper().replace(d))
```

Note: `expression` is your search pattern.

Comment: Wow, that is beautiful. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm getting the error `unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'` on the last line of code, but I'm not sure where it thinks the int is coming from. Any ideas?

Comment: could you share the value of `expression` and value of `diff`?

Comment: I think I'm getting really close. `s.str.findall(expression, 'security')[0]` should be `s.str.findall(expression)` because the object returned is a pd.Series. Each element in that series is a list that is supposed to be the matches. For some reason it doesn't seem like the elements inside the list evaluated the expression correctly (although I've got it to work on other tests). Could you explain what the last bit is supposed to do? I might just go with an ugly but simple work around

Comment: You are right on `findall`. it is a typo on my part. I don't have `diff` and `expression` for testing so I didn't realize that typo. That's why I ask for `diff` and `expression`. I modified the answer to fix all typos. Could you try the edited answer?